# Could someone tell me how to turn this into a listview.builder and still have it connected to firebase? btw the name of my collection is 'groceries'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

Currently it is a listview, I know how to normally create a listview.builder but I don't know how to connect it to firebase. Im talking about the streambuilder and context and all that stuff. Really appreciate any help, Im new to flutter so sorry if this is an obvious/dumb question.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(FireApp());
}

class FireApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FireAppState createState() => _FireAppState();
}
class _FireAppState extends State<FireApp> {
  final TextController = TextEditingController();

  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    CollectionReference groceries =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groceries');

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: TextField(
            controller: TextController,
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: groceries.orderBy('name').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((grocery) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(color: Colors.red,height: 50,child: Text(grocery['name'])),
                    Checkbox(
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                        value: isChecked,
                        activeColor: Colors.black,
                        checkColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                        onChanged: (bool) {
                          setState(() {
                            isChecked = !isChecked;
                          });
                        }
                    )],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
          groceries.add({
            'name': TextController.text,
          });
        },),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

StreamBuilder and listview.builder sample code given below

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  stream: groceries.orderBy('name').snapshots(),
  builder: (context,
      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
    // your list of groceries
    List groceriesList =
        snapshot.data.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: groceriesList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        // build your widget here.
        return Center(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 50,
                child: Text(groceriesList[i]['name']),
              ),
              Checkbox(
                materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                value: isChecked,
                activeColor: Colors.black,
                checkColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                onChanged: (bool) {
                  setState(() => isChecked = !isChecked);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: I just tried that and on the line ```stream: groceries.orderBy('name').snapshots()``` it said The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>?'.

Comment: Sorry about that. Replace `QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` with `QuerySnapshot<Object?>` in 2 places.